# WooCommerce product in a loop and list view

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I am wanting to display each WooCommerce product in a loop while ( $loop -> have_posts() ) : $loop -> the_post(); whilst being displayed in a list view by using the following:

```
do_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary');
```

Could anyone please provide me with a method of how I could achieve this?

This is the following code I have in place:

```
<ul class="products">
<?php
    $args = array( 'post_type' => 'product', 'posts_per_page' => 3 );
    $loop = new WP_Query( $args );

      $interval = 1;

      while ( $loop -> have_posts() ) : $loop -> the_post();

      $productId = get_the_ID();
      $product = get_product( $productId );
      ?>

              <?php if ($interval % 2 != 0): ?>
                <img class="arch" src="/wp-content/uploads/2019/02/main-pages-blue-background-arch-top.png">
              <?php endif; ?>

              <li class="product" style="<?php echo ($interval % 2 != 0 ? "background-color: #f2fafd" : ""); ?>">
                <div class="content">
                  <a href="<?php echo get_permalink( $loop -> post -> ID ) ?>" title="<?php echo esc_attr($loop -> post -> post_title ? $loop -> post -> post_title : $loop -> post -> ID); ?>">

                        do_action( 'woocommerce_before_single_product' );


                  </a>

                </div>
                  <!-- <?php woocommerce_template_loop_add_to_cart( $loop-> post, $product ); ?> -->
              </li>

              <?php if ($interval % 2 != 0): ?>
                <img class="arch arch-bottom" src="/wp-content/uploads/2019/02/main-pages-white-background-arch-top.png">
              <?php endif; ?>

              <?php $interval += 1; ?>
      <?php endwhile; ?>
    <?php wp_reset_query(); ?>
</ul>
```

Essentially I'm trying to place single products in a list view that will then loop through each product for a certain category.

Thanks.

Comment: What have you tried already and why did it not work?

Comment: Hi! If you're doing a manual loop, you it like this: https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/sample-products-loop/

Comment: @Martin Above is the code I am currently using.